# Using KCL 2.x to get DynamoDBEvents from KinesisStream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

From a KinesisClientRecord (record) that I obtained using KCL client, I’m able to get JSON object representing ddb update event from the stream by doing:

```
String recordData = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(record.data()).toString();
JSONObject kinesisRecordObject = new JSONObject(recordData);
```

Now I want to access the fields that I got from the dynamoDB but I can’t deserialise it as its a DynamoDB JSON and not a standard one as explained in this post too [Converting DynamoDB JSON to Standard JSON with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812278/converting-dynamodb-json-to-standard-json-with-java).
The solution given there works DynamoDBStreamRecord but not with KinesisClientRecord(which I’m working with) with  Can you please tell me how this step is to be achieved?
For KCL 1.x I found that KCL Adapter can be used, but I'm using KCL 2.x!

How can I deserialise it to get the fields in the DDB update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using KCL 2 you get CommittableRecord Object from Kinesis. From this you need to extract records().data() which is UTF 8 encoded(by default). The JSON String you get after decoding is then you can convert into desired POJO

Something like this

```
String recordData =
        new StringBuffer(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(committableRecordObject.record().data()))
        .toString();
```