# Converting DynamoDB JSON to Standard JSON with C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

Found this question but it was Java specific, and I need a .net answer:

[Converting DynamoDB JSON to Standard JSON with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812278/converting-dynamodb-json-to-standard-json-with-java)

Anyway to do that in C#? Trying to set up a test framework that reads a json file with the dynamodb json as an input for mocked data. I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should get pretty JSON from the document object using `ToJsonPretty` extension method.

```
Document document = _context.ToDocument(entity); // ignore this line
string jsonString = document.ToJsonPretty(); <--- This is what you need
```

You would need `Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel` namespace for this message.